# GLSL 1.5 & OpenGL 3.3: Passing color to vertex shader seems to fail

Tags: opengl, attributes, colors, glsl, vertex-shader

I have a problem when passing vertex attributes to the running shader program. I'd like to pass two attributes, the position and a RGBA-color. Binding the attribute location works for the position. However, it does not work for the color. Therefore, all the geometry is eventually rendered black.

This is what I do:

```
GLuint programHandler;

// create program
// compile & attach vertex shader
// compile & attach fragment shader

glBindAttribLocation(programHandler, 0, "InPosition");
glBindAttribLocation(programHandler, 1, "InColor");
glBindFragDataLocation(programHandler, 1, "FragColor");

glLinkProgram(programHandler);
glUseProgram(programHandler);

// initialize uniform variables

// I'm trying to get the attribute locations now.
// I expect location "0" for InPosition and location "1" for InColor.
// In fact, it gets me a "-1" for InColor. I simply cannot see the reason for that behaviour

GLint positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programHandler, "InPosition"); // returns 0
GLint colorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programHandler, "InColor"); // returns -1

glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation); // fails!
```

My vertex shader is very basic. All I really do is transforming vertices and passing the color to the fragment shader:

```
#version 150 core

// input
uniform mat4 ModelviewMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
in vec3 InPosition;
in vec4 InColor;

// output
out vec4 PassColor;

void main(void) {
    // passing color through to fragment shader
    PassColor = InColor;

    // transformation
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelviewMatrix * vec4(InPosition, 1.0);
}
```

My fragment shader should simply return that color:

```
#version 150 core
precision highp float;

// input
in vec4 PassColor;

// output
out vec4 FragColor;

void main(void) {
    FragColor = PassColor;
}
```

Why does binding "InPosition" work and "InColor" does not? I am aware that the GLSL compiler optimizes the shader code, so that unused variables cannot be bound. But, I don't see why the color should be optimized out here. After all, I use it by passing it to the fragment shader.

Comment: Any `glGetError()`'s out there? Also, what's your GPU and driver version?

Answer (score 1):

A blind shot, i believe this is wrong:

```
glBindFragDataLocation(programHandler, 1, "FragColor");
```

It should be:

```
glBindFragDataLocation(programHandler, 0, "FragColor");
```

Comment: I see. But what if I want to render to multiple render targets. I currently render to a texture which is attached to a frame buffer object. I originally intended to attach more than only that one texture as color buffers. That's the reason for the "1" as second argument. I believe that gl_FragData[] array is deprecated. How would I bind it correctly and declare that in the fragment shader?

Comment: It is correct but it's rendering to the second render target, if there is one. If there isn't two render targets then it would error.

Comment: So, I assume I would address COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 via FragColor[1] in my GLSL fragment shader. I guess in order to do that, I would need to declare FragColor somewhat like that: "out vec4 FragColor[8];" (assuming there are 8 color buffers attached). Is that correct? Would I also have to bind each frag data location like "glBindFragDataLocation(programHandler, i, "FragColor[i]");"?

Comment: I think you need 8 out variables, not an array.